# I'm getting warn on cassandra log - "Pausing until token count stabilizes"

Tags: cassandra

Someone can please help me to understand what this warning mean?

> "Pausing until token count stabilizes (target=256, actual=282)"

and how can I fix it?

Thanks from ahead ! =)

Comment: Did you perform an operation that might change the tokens?  Such as shuffle?

Comment: Yeah, I perform shuffle create and then shuffle enable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `shuffle` operates in stages, to prevent data loss.

1. Add the tokens to the nodes that are to take over those tokens.
2. Wait for those nodes to have the data transferred to them. At this stage some nodes will have extra tokens.
3. Remove the tokens from the nodes that are no longer to be responsible for them.
4. Remove the data from the nodes that are no longer responsible for it.

I'm guessing this message is saying that the process is currently at stage 2.

Comment: So it's a normal warn? I just need to wait? because its stay like this for a while without continue..